# Derive the sum from an abstract summation. Having trouble understanding the solution to this discrete math problem.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

So I've been working on this problem and after many hours of multiple attempts, I've gotten close to an answer. I honestly would not have figured this out if I didn't have a classmate's help. But I don't understand how they derived the answer.

"Suppose that $q\ne1$ is a constant. Calculate the sum"
$$Sn=\sum_{k=1}^n=kq^k=q+2q^2+3q^3+...+nq^n$$
So I gathered what I could and made this up
$$qSn=q^2+2q^3+3q^4+...nq^{n+1}$$
$$(1-q)Sn=Sn-qSn=q+2q^2-q^2+3q^3-2q^3+4q^4-3q^4+...+q^n-nq^{n+1}$$
$$=q+q^2+q^3+q^4+...q^n-nq^{n+1}$$
That's as far as I could derive, but I confused myself with the end result of $q^n-nq^{n+1}$ which from my understanding means that $q^n$ representing the index number subtracted by $nq^{n+1}$ which is a similar index placement. We can say that the resulting difference would be $(1-q)Sn$. So far, I've been on board but now I had no clue how this is the final answer.
$$Sn =\cfrac{\left(q(1 − q^n)/(1 − q) − nq^{n+1}
\right)}{1 − q}
=\cfrac{\left(q(1 − q^n)− n(1-q)q^{n+1}
\right)}{(1 − q)^2}
$$
I have no clue how this even happens. I understood to get Sn that you would have to divide by 1-q but I cannot put together how they got even the initial portion of the final answer. And I did not even think this would remotely be the answer. For the most part, it just seems that $kq^k$ would be the best answer anyways to these problems.

Comment: Initial portion of the final answer: Just use the formula for  a geometric sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have

$$S_n - qS_n = q+q^2+\cdots + q^n - nq^{n+1}.$$

Now, use the fact that $$1+q+q^2+\cdots + q^n = \frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}$$

and you get

$$(1-q)S_n = -1 + \frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q} - nq^{n+1}$$

then just simplify.

Comment: Is this related to the geometric sum formula? A friend just told me that this is a variation of it.

Comment: @D.S. Well, yes, $1+q+\cdots + q^n = \frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}$ is exactly the geometric sum.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that for me. That actually cleared some of the confusion for this for me. I didn't see there was an application of the geometric sum formula, but it seems that I didn't have that clearly defined for me from lectures and my textbook.